# Launching python within python and timezone issue

Tags: python, django, datetime, timezone

I had to make a launcher script for my django app, and it seems it somehow switches the timezone to GMT (default being +2), and every datetime is two hours behind when using the script. What could be causing that?

Here is the launcher script that I use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import subprocess
import shlex
import time

cwd = os.getcwd()

p1 = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("python manage.py runserver"),
        cwd=os.path.join(cwd, "drugsworld"))
p2 = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("python coffee_auto_compiler.py"),
        cwd=os.path.join(cwd))

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(2)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    p1.terminate()
    p2.terminate()
```

If I manually run `python manage.py runserver`, the timezone is +2. If, however, I use this script, the timezone is set to GMT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm. Python respects the TZ environment variable... you're not changing it in your script, so it **should** be equivalent to running it at the shell.

I often set the time zone explicitly. In Django specifically, you can set this in the settings.py file (TIME_ZONE). More general python is:

```
os.environ['TZ']="America/New_York"
time.tzset()
```

I imagine if you set the timezone in your settings file, the problem will go away.

Answer (score 3):

Following up on [Robert's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4694988/launching-python-within-python-and-timezone-issue/4695052#4695052), you might try adding the `env` parameter to the `Popen` call. For example:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["date"], env={'TZ':'America/New_York'})
p.wait()
# Fri Jan 14 14:45:44 EST 2011

p = subprocess.Popen(["date"], env={'TZ':'Asia/Taipei'})
p.wait()
# Sat Jan 15 03:45:44 CST 2011
```